# Background-clip: content-box won't work

Tags: css

I'm learning web development and I'm currently "finishing" with css, but I am stuck at **backround-clip** property, more precisely **content-box** value. However I try, it just won't work and it looks like I set it to *padding-box*. Also notice I didn't use `background` (shorthand property).

There must be something I'm missing. My main source of learning this property is [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-clip/) and as you can see, my example follows it almost to the letter. Anyway, here's the *JSFiddle* link and see it for yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/av857arj/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your boxes have no padding, so the padding-box and content-box will look the same. When you add padding to all three boxes, you can see the difference.

```css
#clip-ex-container {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.clip-ex-bb, .clip-ex-pb, .clip-ex-cb {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 1em;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  background-color: rgb(189, 218, 49);
  border: 0.6em solid rgba(54, 80, 65, 0.49);
  padding: 1em;
}

.clip-ex-bb {
  background-clip: border-box;
  margin-left: 2.9em;
}
.clip-ex-pb {background-clip: padding-box;}
.clip-ex-cb {background-clip: content-box;}
```

```html
<div id="clip-ex-container" class="clearfix">
  <div class="clip-ex-bb">
    <p>Border Box</p>
  </div>
  <div class="clip-ex-pb">
    <p>Padding Box</p>
  </div>
  <div class="clip-ex-cb">
    <p>Content Box</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would never thought of that. This solved my problem, thanks a lot!